# files created on internal hard drive are always owned by root

Tags: mount, hard-disk, root, fstab

When I ssh into my computer, files I create on the main hard drive are owned by me:

> $ touch test
>   $ ls -l test
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 smithty domain users 0 Aug 16 17:26 test

But when I move into a folder that's on a second hard drive, everything I create is owned by root as default:

> $ cd data
>   $ touch test
>   $ ls -l test
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 16 17:28 test

I assume this is because I'm doing something wrong when I mount this drive, but I'm not sure what. I use the following config in `/etc/fstab`:

> UUID=A88667B486678224 /media/data ntfs rw,nosuid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async 0 2

I originally used the `defaults` option, but thought that shifting to `nosuid` would fix this. It hasn't though. Have I done something wrong in my fstab, or is there something else amiss.

This is on Ubuntu 14.04.1. My login shell is dash, but the problem is the same if I switch to bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NTFS doesn't know what a Linux user id is.  It doesn't store such metadata.  So everything gets to be root.

ext4/xfs (which is what your main hard drive likely is) does know it.

You might want to mount using the ["uid=xxx option, see man page"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I was worried I'd somehow managed to silently turn on sudo for the whole drive!

Comment: If you need to interoperate with Windows, [NTFS-3G can be set up to understand user IDs](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#7).

Comment: Thanks @Mark . I don't actually have to interoperate with Windows with this machine. Our IT department is new to Linux, and it looks like they formatted the second hard drive from a Windows computer. If I hadn't already put 400G of data on it I'd reformat it to ext4